# how to scrape data from www.immoweb.be (belgian real estate platform) with python?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I write to you because I would like to get help in web scraping. I am a beginner in python and web scraping. I would like to be able to extract information from a real estate site and contain it in an Excel file. My problem (due to my lack of knowledge in scraping) is that I don't know how to reach the desired information. I would like to obtain the price and address of each house presented on the web page.

I started to write something but I'm lost in the for loop. What must be added to obtain the address and the price? Thanks for your help. Cheers.

```
  url = "https://www.immoweb.be/fr/recherche/maison/a-vendre/ixelles/1050?countries=BE&orderBy=newest"
  response = requests.get(url)
  print(response.status_code)
  parser = html.fromstring(response.text)
  search_results = parser.xpath("//main/iw-search")
  properties_list = []
        
  for properties in search_results:
      raw_address = properties.xpath("<add something>")
      raw_price = properties.xpath("<add something>")
      ...
```

Comment: Any ideas about my issue? :(

Comment: This website uses JS to create results. Not easy to scrape at all. You definitely have to use Selenium but I'm not sure it can work either.

Comment: Hello,
I'm working on same topic and i'm curious to know if you solved your issue?

Answer (score 2):

This is a dynamic website. Thus, you need you use a WebDriver.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
# pip install selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome

drive = Chrome(executable_path =r"/Users/faridmammadaliyev/Desktop/chromedriver")
drive.get('https://www.immoweb.be/en/classified/apartment/for-sale/antwerpen/2000/9614247')
soup = BeautifulSoup(drive.page_source, "lxml")
jobs_elements = soup.find_all("tr", class_= "classified-table__row")
```

Then, you are ready to scrape:

```
data = []

for jobs_element in jobs_elements:
    try:
        table_data = jobs_element.find("td", class_="classified-table__data").text.strip()
    
    # if you dont add except .text method will produce an error
    except AttributeError:
        table_data = 'no data'
    
    try:
        table_header = jobs_element.find("th", class_="classified-table__header").text.strip()
    
    # if you dont add except .text method will produce an error
    except AttributeError:
        table_header = 'no data'
    
    item = {'table_data':table_data,
            'table_header': table_header}
    
    data.append(item)
    
print(data)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df
```

The check the following article for more details.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I followed Farid's way of doing it and I want to add that with Selenium 4 and later, the recommended way to specify the path to the WebDriver executable is through Service.

So instead of using:

```
from selenium 
import webdriver

drive = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/path/to/chromedriver')
```

use:

```
from selenium 
import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service('/path/to/chromedriver')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
```

Comment: Please follow [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) to properly format your code blocks.